# Convert Json Array to js Objects

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

Hello All I want to convert this json array to other format from 
    [{
      "name": "Before 9",
      "y": "0"
    }, {
      "name": "9-30",
      "y": "0"
    }, {
      "name": "9.30-10.00",
      "y": "0"
    }, {
      "name": "10.00-10.30",
      "y": null
    }, {
      "name": "10.30-11.00",
      "y": null
    }, {
      "name": "Over 11",
      "y": null
    }]

To

```
[{
  name: "Before 9",
  y: 0
}, {
  name: "9-30",
  y: 0
}, {
  name: "9.30-10.00",
  y: 0
}, {
  name: "10.00-10.30",
  y: null
}, {
  name: "10.30-11.00",
  y: null
}, {
  name: "Over 11",
  y: null
}]
```

Please provide some solution with java script and Angular Js ,Php

Thanks

Comment: Please provide us with a payment

Comment: Please provide us with more initiative

Comment: Why do you think you need to convert this format? In JS terms (object notation) they are both equal.

Comment: Adding on chart last format is working first not ...any solution

Comment: I think the only thing you have changed is remvoed the quotes around `name`. Tell us why you want to do that ? What exactly have you done that has gone wrong ?

Comment: Could it be that the first, as a whole, is a string and the 2nd is something you assigned *by hand* to some variable? If so, is the first something you get from a server? There a probably better ways, but have you tried [`JSON.parse(...)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse)?

Comment: actually i have get data from json array by php json_encode function that shows first array i want this json to update my chart.js which require second format ..other charts like highchart also use this format ..i want to convert my first format to second..

Comment: Again, the first and the second are equal when it comes to js execution. Please show the wohle code and the code you use to generate this code. Currently no one can help you.

Comment: http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/series   want data: [{
    name: 'Point 1',
    color: '#00FF00',
    y: 0
}, {
    name: 'Point 2',
    color: '#FF00FF',
    y: 5
}]  Want this format from php json_encode that provide my first given type output

Comment: Ok, I'm giving up here. You did not provide enough information so that someone can help you. I'd suggest going back and read some good javascript tutorials. // And one last time, the quotes do not make the code different. https://jsfiddle.net/b9v8p437/ There is something else wrong with your code, and you're fixating on the wrong solution.

Answer (score 2):

I guess that first is json string, so you need to have an Array object: `JSON.parse('[{"name":"Before 9","y":"0"},{"name":"9-30","y":"0"},{"name":"9.30-10.00","y":"0"},{"name":"10.00-10.30","y":null},{"name":"10.30-11.00","y":null},{"name":"Over 11","y":null}]');`